# S3 bucket objects are not getting deleted by s3.deleteObject() method

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've used the s3.deleteObject() method to delete the uploaded file on AWS S3 bucket. But in response, I'm getting no error but still not deletion of that file. I thought it could be permission issue but, I'm not event getting permission error and this file is already uploaded by multerS3.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});
const s3 = new aws.S3();

(async () => {
  let params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket',
    Key: 'https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/1648634140824-xyz.png'
  };

  console.log(`params ->> `, params);

  s3.deleteObject(params, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`\nDeleteImageFromS3 error ->> ${error}`);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('\ns3.deleteObject data ->> ', data);
      return;
    }
  });
})();
```

In **response**, I'm getting below log and file is still existing in **S3 bucket**

```
s3.deleteObject data ->>  { DeleteMarker: true,
  VersionId: 'DtD9ccuW2zl1ylWvQTrjJfk3yVa_Ze1A' }
```

**Thank you advance**

Comment: You have versioning enabled. The object is deleted in the sense that its delete marker is set.

Comment: Not sure what the key in your context actually is but I hope it is not `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/1648634140824-xyz.png` - the key should only be `profiles/1648634140824-xyz.png`.

Comment: @luk2302 , thanks for answering, but can you tell me that delete maker is set means, after some specific time it'll be deleted?

Comment: Not unless you have lifecycle rules configured. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/manage-objects-versioned-bucket.html But the more important point is my second comment: do you actually delete the correct key!?

Comment: @luk2302, 'profiles/1648634140824-xyz.png' is damn working dude. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the key part, you wont have have to define the domain of aws s3 (all these things are handled by `aws-sdk` only), just the file name present inside that bucket.

```
 let params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket',
    Key: 'profiles/1648634140824-xyz.png'
  };
```